Using IFX getting Error Opening Source File message
I'm debugging my Fortran files recently changing from ifort to ifx, then I got a weird problem.
Every time jumping from a subroutine to another subroutine, I get the error shown in the picture, but when I hit Step Into it will go to the right source file successfully. Could somebody help to explain?

The content of more information is below:
Locating source for 'C:\Users\baihaodong\Documents\2024Tasks_78_102424\1.Yodogawa_Comparison\new_927\Yodogawa_Salinity\src\src\data_io.F90'. (No checksum.)
Found partial match #1: C:\Users\baihaodong\Documents\2024Tasks_78_102424\1.Yodogawa_Comparison\new_927\Yodogawa_Salinity\src\src\data_io.F90 (No checksum.)
The debugger will use the source at location 1.
Opening file 'C:\Users\baihaodong\Documents\2024Tasks_78_102424\1.Yodogawa_Comparison\new_927\Yodogawa_Salinity\src\src\data_io.F90' in the source file editor failed. Operation not supported. Unknown error: 0x80070057.

When switching to ifort, it works without error

Please do not use pictures for error messages. When quoting error messages from pictures, copy them exactly as text (by that I mean namely the text at the top of the picture errir box). It is really important. See [ask] and [mcve].

The path reported in the picture contains very strange characters, namely ¥ instead of . I recommend asking at the official support forum at Intel and reporting the language setting of your operating system. It is quite unlikely that someone else will know the details, this is a problem for Intel.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

The error message asks you to check whether the source file contains any non-printable characters. Did you do this check? Do you use any kanji or hiragana or any other non-Latin script in the files? If yes, report that to Intel as well. I highly recommend to use non-ASCII characters only inside character strings. I also recommend to do all code comments in English, but others may disagree.

@VladimirFГероямслава Thanks for your kind answers, I'm sorry that using the picture rather than text for error messages and late reply.
Actually, I asked the question in intel fortran forum, but I haven't got the answer, maybe my description is not enough.
What I want is how to avoid this error message while it doesn't matter the actual debugging process.
Even using . in path or using all English character the error insists.
Notice that changing to ifort the error message will disappear.

I understand. But I don't think it is the file path, although it could be. It is more likely something in the file. Aren't there any comments in Japanese inside? Or some other strange characters?

I appreciate your response. Actually, I think I removed all japanese while the error still appears. Also, this error appears during simple program with three files each contains one subroutine below:
main.F90:
program main
implicit none
call subA()
print *, "Hello, world!"
end program main
subA.F90:
subroutine subA()
implicit none
print *, "subA"
call subB()
end subroutine subA
subB.F90:
subroutine subB()
implicit none
print *, "subB"
end subroutine subB
Then rebuild it using IFX from visual studio 2022 (all the configuration may be default using Debug config).
